# RecyclerView itemClickListener in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I'm writing an app in Kotlin
but confused as to how to utilize itemClickListener with a RecyclerView in Kotlin.

this my custom listener

```
class RecyclerTouchListener(
context: Context?,
recycleView: RecyclerView,
private val clicklistener: ClickListener?) : OnItemTouchListener {
private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
    if (child != null && clicklistener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clicklistener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child))
    }
    return false
}

override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}
override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}

interface ClickListener {
    fun onClick(view: View?, position: Int)
    fun onLongClick(view: View?, position: Int)
}

init {
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, object : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
            val child = recycleView.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
            if (child != null && clicklistener != null) {
                clicklistener.onLongClick(child, recycleView.getChildAdapterPosition(child))
            }
        }
    })
} }//end RecyclerTouchListener class
```

And I tried to use it in my MainActivity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val list:ArrayList<Item> = ArrayList()
val myAdapter =ItemRcyclerAdapter(this , fillItemArray())

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val main_item_recycler: RecyclerView= findViewById(R.id.main_item_recycler)

    main_item_recycler.adapter=myAdapter
    main_item_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
    main_item_recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    main_item_recycler.addOnItemTouchListener(RecyclerTouchListener(
        this,main_item_recycler, RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener(){
      
          }))
}//end onCreate()
```

But in RecyclerTouchListener constructor I can not pass this parameter " RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() " right

**how can i do it to override   ClickListener interface methods?
and Is it the best way to set listeners on recyclerView?**

Comment: Why you implementing it with touch listener? is there any reason that you do not implement your click listeners inside RecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: i don’t quite know why i used this method, i was looking for a solution online and found it.
do you know what are the reasons we might use this method instead of another?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your click listeners inside your adapter instead of implementing gesture detector to get child views.
I've added sample code that you can see how to implement that:

```
class YourAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.YourViewHolder>() {
    
    var items: List<YourItem> = emptyList()
    
    var onItemClicked: ((tem: YourItem) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): YourViewHolder {
        // Create your View Holder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[holder.adapterPosition])
    }

    inner class YourViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(item: YourItem) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener { 
                onItemClicked?.invoke(item)
            }
        }

    }
}

data class YourItem(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String
)

class YourActivity: Activity() {

    val adapter = YourAdapter()
    
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.items = // Set your data
        adapter.onItemClicked = {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: i don’t quite know why i used this method, i was looking for a solution online and found it.
do you know what are the reasons we might use this method instead of another?

Comment: @YousefAwad this is a better aproach and also best practise. cause you are filling your views with data and you have access to both of them with position